# Google Cloud Vision Logo Detection API - failing to identify logos

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, google-vision

I am trying to scrape images from websites and use Google Cloud Vision API to detect if an image on the website is a logo. It works if I provide it a logo like Apple, but it doesn't seem to work for well known non fortune-500 tech company logos (e.g., LaunchDarkly, LogDNA, etc) despite the images clearly being logos. Is it supposed to work for any type of logo or only large brands? Is there a solution out there better suited for my needs?

```
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
with io.open('./img.png', 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()
        image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
        response = client.logo_detection(image=image)
        logos = response.logo_annotations
        for logo in logos:
            print(logo.description)
            print(logo.score)

        if response.error.message:
            raise Exception(
                '{}\nFor more info on error messages, check: '
                'https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors'.format(
                    response.error.message))
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-logos), Logo Detection detects **popular** product logos. It is expected that it doesn't detect logos with which the model has not been trained.

The solution you can try within CGP is [AutoML Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs). This product allows you to retrain GCP's models to classify your images according to your own defined labels. You can create a dataset with the logos you need to detect and retrain the models with it. It has a very easy interface to be able to do it even if you don't have any Machine Learning expertise.

Comment: Is it possible to train automl to detect logos within an image, for example detect the trained logos in a website screenshot?

Comment: Yes, AutoML Vision is designed for that purpose. Please check the documentation mentioned above.